# android studio 3.2.1 ставится без sdk

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

поставил студию 3.2.1 с оф сайта, sdk взял отсюда https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip скинул содержимое в отдельную папку AndroidSDK, указываю студии эту папку, говорит "SDK does not contain any platforms"

Comment: Ну мало просто скинуть, надо бы еще и из зипа достать. Но вообще непонятно, зачем такой странный способ. Можно же напрямую из АС загрузить и установить.

Comment: @Эникейщик достал конечно же из зипа. А из студии не могу скачать. В окне Select SDK при указании папки с распакованным архивом пишет "selected dirctory is not valid home for android sdk"

Comment: Какая папка? Может, там кириллица в пути (мало ли).

Comment: @Эникейщик нету кириллицы. Папка в корне диска D

Comment: Я бы попробовал сначала установить в папку по дефолту, чтобы убедиться, что работает. А потом уже можно и перенести, если есть необходимость.